# What is cyan color in Japanese?

Tags: english-to-japanese, colors

What is the exact word for **cyan** color in Japanese language? Is it 青緑 / あおみどり?

Comment: You might want to add color codes here or at least specify a little more detail about how you define cyan. 青緑 is literally "blue-green" and seems to be a color similar to cyan (?), but if someone asked me the difference between blue-green and cyan in English I wouldn't be able to answer.

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3_(%E8%89%B2)

Answer (score 10):

If you think of *cyan* in a technical sense, for example as one of the primary colours in the CMYK model (so `(100,0,0,0)`) (in the RGB model probably `(0,255,255)`), then in Japanese it would be シアン ([シアン on Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3_(%E8%89%B2))).

As you can find in the Wikipedia article, there are several colour names, which compare to シアン as follows:

- シアン

  > [image: シアン]
- 青緑【あおみどり】・青緑色【せいりょくしょく】

  > [image: 青緑]
- 藍緑色【らんりょくしょく】

  > [image: 藍緑色]
- アクアマリン

  > [image: アクアマリン]
- 水色【みずいろ】

  > [image: 水色]

The pictures are from a Google Image search. (I tried to restrict the search to results from Japan, but somehow there are still some results from Chinese websites. Still, I think the strategy is clear here.)